# Unable to run powershell script within powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, office365, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

If i run this code it will run the file

```
{Write-host "Please Enter the email address of the user you want to check the permissions"
 $user = Read-Host
 Powershell.exe  C:\Temp\Report\Reports.ps1}
```

But if i run it like this which is what i need to do

```
{ Write-host "Please Enter the email address of the user you want to check the permissions"
 $user = Read-Host
 Powershell.exe  C:\Temp\Report\Reports.ps1 -processOneDrive $true -OneDriveEmail $user}
```

I get this error

```
Powershell.exe : C:\Temp\ReportSharedFiles\ReportSharedFiles.ps1 : Missing an argument for parameter 'OneDriveEmail'. Specify a 
At C:\Temp\ReportSharedFiles\Full Exchange Script Menu.ps1:88 char:2
+  Powershell.exe "c:\Temp\ReportSharedFiles\ReportSharedFiles.ps1" -pr ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Temp\ReportS...il'. Specify a :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
At line:1 char:71
+ ... haredFiles\ReportSharedFiles.ps1 -processOneDrive True -OneDriveEmail
+                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ReportSharedFiles.ps1], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,ReportSharedFiles.ps1
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i get this to work? any help will be appreciated

Comment: is your reports.ps1 file calling C:\Temp\Report\Full Exchange Script Menu.ps1. If so check line:88 char:2 in Full Exchange Script Menu.ps1
There is a conflict with the switches -processOneDrive $true -OneDriveEmail $user

Comment: @ClintOliveira sorry was wrong error, i fixed that and changed edited the error. this is what i have for line 88 ```Powershell.exe "c:\Temp\Report\Reports.ps1" -processOneDrive $true -OneDriveEmail``` its like it doesn't like reading the arguments i put in for some reason. Without them it will work fine but i need them in

Answer (score 0):

I believe its asking you for a sting parameter in the error

> parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.

Hope this works out>

```
 { [string]$user = Read-Host "Please Enter the email address of the user you want to check the permissions"
 Powershell.exe  C:\Temp\Report\Reports.ps1 -processOneDrive $true -OneDriveEmail $user}
```

Type String >
[image]

Comment: That can't be it, but tried and still error. If i code it without the arguments ```-processOneDrive $true -oneDriveEmail $user``` then it will run the powershell script. However i need to use those arguments. Only when they are placed in then it cause the error. Im wondering if im doing something wrong when calling the other script and adding arguments in at same time. Is it even possible to do. I know if i ran this in a powershell command too it will run fine with the argument in. Its only when running a powershell script with in a powershell script that it causes errors with the arguments in

Comment: If the the PowerShell command and it works the issue has to be with how those parameters are used while calling the 'Full Exchange Script Menu.ps1' script

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. It seems when running the powershell script within another script and to have the arguments in. when it comes to the -processOneDrive $true It tried to convert that to boolem which caused errors. i changed this to 1 which im sure means true so code looks like this

```
Powershell.exe "c:\Temp\Report\Reports.ps1" -processOneDrive 1 -OneDriveEmail $user
```

Now it runs smoothly. Thanks for everyone that tried to help me with this :)